# Why Am I Missing Alchemy Formula?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

One of the last things I have to do is complete 120 alchemy recipes. I was planning to use the formula I've collected as an in-game checklist, since it shows a **?** if you haven't yet made an item.

As I began paging through my list I noticed that I'm missing a lot of very basic formula. For instance, formulas 1 through 5: Sandwich, Fishburger, Cheeseburger, Tonic, and Pixie Dew. I realize that I can just make these by following a guide online, and *it does count towards my alchemy total*, but I'm curious - where would I find these recipes that I've missed?

If it helps the only remaining quest I have is to complete the **War God's Ax**.

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems like a legitimate question with a not obvious answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [FAQ/Walkthrough by Malduke](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/998014-ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch/faqs/65904?page=6#section1075):

The formula come from talking with random people and completing errands.

- Castaway Cove - woman on a small boat at the docks
- Hamelin - gray haired man in front of Swift Solutions
- Skull Mountain - sky pirate on the Iron Wyvern
- Yule - ice-fishing tomte
- Perdida - boy next to woman holding a baby llapaca
- Perdida - Xanaduvian guard
- **Errands**

  - 021: A Tail of Woe
  - 040: A Change of Heart
  - 057: The Mechanic's Lament
  - 059: Moving On
  - 064: The Hungry Llapaca
  - 069: The Runaway Fairies
  - 076: The Young Alchemist
  - 077: The Forest Alchemists
  - 078: The Master Alchemist
  - 085: Notes from the Center
- **Master Alchemist** (*after completing his errand and holding two items*)

  - Heart of the Muse - Solosseum Series Rank A prize
  - Cad's Clasp - Porco Rosso drop